# Event table from Hazelcast

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, wso2-cep

I am using below execution plan to populate my hazelcast backed event table.
Problem is, how can I reuse this existing hazelcast backed event table from another execution plan ?

It is a followup question for another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463937/wso2-cep-single-event-table-for-multiple-execution-plans).

```
@Import('users:1.0.0')
define stream users (meta_name string, correlation_id int);

@from(eventtable = 'hazelcast', cluster.name = 'cluster_a', cluster.password = 'pass@cluster_a')
define table UserTable (name string, id int) ;

from users
select meta_name as name, correlation_id as id
insert OVERWRITE UserTable
  on UserTable.id == id;
```

Comment: Are you using CEP 4.2.0?

Comment: Yes, I am using 4.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same `collection.name` in both execution plans. You don't need to use `cluster.name` and `cluster.password`. Refer to following example;

**Execution Plan 1**

```
@Plan:name('TestIn')

@Import('dataIn:1.0.0')
define stream dataIn (id int, name string);

@from(eventtable = 'hazelcast', collection.name='hzTable')
define table hzTable (id int, name string);

from dataIn
insert into hzTable;
```

**Execution Plan 2**

```
@Plan:name('TestOut')

@Export('dataOut:1.0.0')
define stream dataOut (id int, name string);

@from(eventtable = 'hazelcast', collection.name='hzTable')
define table hzTable (id int, name string);

define trigger periodicTrigger at every 2 sec;

from periodicTrigger join hzTable
select hzTable.id as id, hzTable.name as name
insert into dataOut;
```

Comment: Hi Granier, it is working exactly how suggested here.

Comment: Working for WSO2 CEP 4.2.0